# Can someone please explain fenwick trees to me?

Tags: algorithm, tree, sum

So what I think is it's like a max-heap, the children are bigger, every subtree is a sum of its children, but that wouldn't make sense, and can be easily replaced by a normal max-heap, no need to add all the children, that's why I think I'm wrong about fenwick trees, can someone explain them to me; if I'm right, why're they useful?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions of this sort are better suited to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) than to stack overflow.

Comment: @pjs you can ask questions on wikipedia?

Comment: No, but you can get pretty solid explanations.  Did you look at the link provided in my comment? You might also want to look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) here on SO to see what sorts of questions are suitable for this site.

Comment: @pjs oh! I'l go see the help center